# Installing CyanogenMod changed phone number, no voice service

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, mobile-network, cyanogenmod

A few days ago, I installed cyanogenmod on my phone (From [here](http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install)), and I noticed that my phone couldn't get or send calls or texts. When I went to Settings>About>Status, the phone number and MIN showed 000000xxxx (x's are numbers), and it said I was roaming, but I fixed that by changing the preferred network mode to CDMA, so I was able to get mobile data, but still no voice service. I used Odin to flash back to the stock rom, but the problems persist, and now I don't get any service. I can provide any more details if needed.

Comment: Please go and delete your other question, as it is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Did you read the changelog and bugs for the ROM from the developers website (the forum you got it from)?

Comment: I used an automatic installer to do it, as I linked.

Comment: Without proper info, help is going to be difficult. What build is being used? If your not getting phone after flashing stock again, did you make sure that the modem (radio) is the correct version?

Comment: How do I find if I have the right modem?

Comment: Also, the only 2 other cases I have seen ([here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1870972) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1940190)) were both solved by calling *2767*3855# to reprovision the phone, but when I do that it says the number is invalid?

Comment: You can only use that code on stock firmware. As far as the modem you'd have to search for what one goes with what version of android your using.

Comment: Also to paraphrase one of the replies on the second page in the second link you provided "the code to reprovision the simcard will not work on newer firmware". So it won't work on kitkat (cm11)

Comment: I flashed it back to the stock firmware, it still says the number is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any other way to reprovision the sim card? Would my carrier provide a new sim card, and would that help? Thanks for being so helpful, by the way.

Comment: I'll do some digging for you tomorrow and get you an answer for you

Comment: Make sure you have the correct APN selected: Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> More -> Cellular Networks -> Access Point Names (Path to this setting may be different, but this should be close).

Comment: My phone doesn't have an APN setting